Custom command-line tool EZDXF
We just come across this online tool but we cannot use it because we don't know anything about Python.
We have a strange problem exporting R12 DXFs from the latest version of Siemens NX CAD, which have errors being imported in iMill, an ancient CAM software but unfortunately our only gateway to drive our CNC mill.
iMill only seems to accept R12 DXFs from Draftsight, for some strange reason we are almost sure someone here of the developers of EZDXF could discover by comparing both DXFs
We are hoping a pass through EZDXF could solve this.
Can some one here, help? Who develops EZDXF?
Thanks!
Regards,
We didn't try anything, we wouldn't know how to run EZDXF

You can start a new discussion on github maybe I can help.
